# Replacement parts for a Sunset GD-3000 tripod

Tags: tripod

I was cleaning out my parent's home when I came across a Sunset GD-3000 tripod which seems strong enough to support my 90mm telescope.

Unfortunately, two parts are missing, the screw that holds the camera to the top, and the handle that controls the tilt.

It appears that the camera screw is a 1/4"-20 thread screw, so that is easy to replace. What about the handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a standard handle for photographic tripods (there might be a standard for motion pictures, but that’s an entirely different industry and economics).

Your best bet is almost certainly fabricating something yourself.

Or swapping heads, if that’s possible, is probably a better bet.

Finally, US eBay shows several for sale, so you could buy a donor if there is an emotional bond to that specific tripod…but it also looks like the GD-3000 head might be replaceable from the listing photos.

Comment: Oh that’s sad to here, but very useful nonetheless. Thanks.